# Quality of Generated Image is Low

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-to-image

I have this simple code

```js
function appendImg(imageData) {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = imageData;
    document.getElementById("img-out-preview").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("img-out-preview").appendChild(img);
    document.getElementById("img-preview-div").style.display = "block";
}

function saveAsPng() {
    var element = document.getElementById('output-location');

    domtoimage.toPng(element, {style: {transform: "scale(2)"}})
        .then(function (dataUrl) { appendImg(dataUrl) })
        .catch(function (error) { console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error); });
}

function saveAsSvg() {
    const filter = (node) => { return (node.tagName !== 'i'); }

    domtoimage.toSvg(document.getElementById('output-location'), {filter: filter})
        .then(function (dataUrl) { appendImg(dataUrl) })
        .catch(function (error) { console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error); });
}

$("#save-svg").on("click", saveAsSvg);
$("#save-png").on("click", saveAsPng);

/*! dom-to-image 10-06-2017 */
!function(a){"use strict";function b(a,b){function c(a){return b.bgcolor&&(a.style.backgroundColor=b.bgcolor),b.width&&(a.style.width=b.width+"px"),b.height&&(a.style.height=b.height+"px"),b.style&&Object.keys(b.style).forEach(function(c){a.style[c]=b.style[c]}),a}return b=b||{},g(b),Promise.resolve(a).then(function(a){return i(a,b.filter,!0)}).then(j).then(k).then(c).then(function(c){return l(c,b.width||q.width(a),b.height||q.height(a))})}function c(a,b){return h(a,b||{}).then(function(b){return b.getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,q.width(a),q.height(a)).data})}function d(a,b){return h(a,b||{}).then(function(a){return a.toDataURL()})}function e(a,b){return b=b||{},h(a,b).then(function(a){return a.toDataURL("image/jpeg",b.quality||1)})}function f(a,b){return h(a,b||{}).then(q.canvasToBlob)}function g(a){"undefined"==typeof a.imagePlaceholder?v.impl.options.imagePlaceholder=u.imagePlaceholder:v.impl.options.imagePlaceholder=a.imagePlaceholder,"undefined"==typeof a.cacheBust?v.impl.options.cacheBust=u.cacheBust:v.impl.options.cacheBust=a.cacheBust}function h(a,c){function d(a){var b=document.createElement("canvas");if(b.width=c.width||q.width(a),b.height=c.height||q.height(a),c.bgcolor){var d=b.getContext("2d");d.fillStyle=c.bgcolor,d.fillRect(0,0,b.width,b.height)}return b}return b(a,c).then(q.makeImage).then(q.delay(100)).then(function(b){var c=d(a);return c.getContext("2d").drawImage(b,0,0),c})}function i(a,b,c){function d(a){return a instanceof HTMLCanvasElement?q.makeImage(a.toDataURL()):a.cloneNode(!1)}function e(a,b,c){function d(a,b,c){var d=Promise.resolve();return b.forEach(function(b){d=d.then(function(){return i(b,c)}).then(function(b){b&&a.appendChild(b)})}),d}var e=a.childNodes;return 0===e.length?Promise.resolve(b):d(b,q.asArray(e),c).then(function(){return b})}function f(a,b){function c(){function c(a,b){function c(a,b){q.asArray(a).forEach(function(c){b.setProperty(c,a.getPropertyValue(c),a.getPropertyPriority(c))})}a.cssText?b.cssText=a.cssText:c(a,b)}c(window.getComputedStyle(a),b.style)}function d(){function c(c){function d(a,b,c){function d(a){var b=a.getPropertyValue("content");return a.cssText+" content: "+b+";"}function e(a){function b(b){return b+": "+a.getPropertyValue(b)+(a.getPropertyPriority(b)?" !important":"")}return q.asArray(a).map(b).join("; ")+";"}var f="."+a+":"+b,g=c.cssText?d(c):e(c);return document.createTextNode(f+"{"+g+"}")}var e=window.getComputedStyle(a,c),f=e.getPropertyValue("content");if(""!==f&&"none"!==f){var g=q.uid();b.className=b.className+" "+g;var h=document.createElement("style");h.appendChild(d(g,c,e)),b.appendChild(h)}}[":before",":after"].forEach(function(a){c(a)})}function e(){a instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement&&(b.innerHTML=a.value),a instanceof HTMLInputElement&&b.setAttribute("value",a.value)}function f(){b instanceof SVGElement&&(b.setAttribute("xmlns","http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"),b instanceof SVGRectElement&&["width","height"].forEach(function(a){var c=b.getAttribute(a);c&&b.style.setProperty(a,c)}))}return b instanceof Element?Promise.resolve().then(c).then(d).then(e).then(f).then(function(){return b}):b}return c||!b||b(a)?Promise.resolve(a).then(d).then(function(c){return e(a,c,b)}).then(function(b){return f(a,b)}):Promise.resolve()}function j(a){return s.resolveAll().then(function(b){var c=document.createElement("style");return a.appendChild(c),c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(b)),a})}function k(a){return t.inlineAll(a).then(function(){return a})}function l(a,b,c){return Promise.resolve(a).then(function(a){return a.setAttribute("xmlns","http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"),(new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(a)}).then(q.escapeXhtml).then(function(a){return'<foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">'+a+"</foreignObject>"}).then(function(a){return'<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="'+b+'" height="'+c+'">'+a+"</svg>"}).then(function(a){return"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,"+a})}function m(){function a(){var a="application/font-woff",b="image/jpeg";return{woff:a,woff2:a,ttf:"application/font-truetype",eot:"application/vnd.ms-fontobject",png:"image/png",jpg:b,jpeg:b,gif:"image/gif",tiff:"image/tiff",svg:"image/svg+xml"}}function b(a){var b=/\.([^\.\/]*?)$/g.exec(a);return b?b[1]:""}function c(c){var d=b(c).toLowerCase();return a()[d]||""}function d(a){return a.search(/^(data:)/)!==-1}function e(a){return new Promise(function(b){for(var c=window.atob(a.toDataURL().split(",")[1]),d=c.length,e=new Uint8Array(d),f=0;f<d;f++)e[f]=c.charCodeAt(f);b(new Blob([e],{type:"image/png"}))})}function f(a){return a.toBlob?new Promise(function(b){a.toBlob(b)}):e(a)}function g(a,b){var c=document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(),d=c.createElement("base");c.head.appendChild(d);var e=c.createElement("a");return c.body.appendChild(e),d.href=b,e.href=a,e.href}function h(){var a=0;return function(){function b(){return("0000"+(Math.random()*Math.pow(36,4)<<0).toString(36)).slice(-4)}return"u"+b()+a++}}function i(a){return new Promise(function(b,c){var d=new Image;d.onload=function(){b(d)},d.onerror=c,d.src=a})}function j(a){var b=3e4;return v.impl.options.cacheBust&&(a+=(/\?/.test(a)?"&":"?")+(new Date).getTime()),new Promise(function(c){function d(){if(4===g.readyState){if(200!==g.status)return void(h?c(h):f("cannot fetch resource: "+a+", status: "+g.status));var b=new FileReader;b.onloadend=function(){var a=b.result.split(/,/)[1];c(a)},b.readAsDataURL(g.response)}}function e(){h?c(h):f("timeout of "+b+"ms occured while fetching resource: "+a)}function f(a){console.error(a),c("")}var g=new XMLHttpRequest;g.onreadystatechange=d,g.ontimeout=e,g.responseType="blob",g.timeout=b,g.open("GET",a,!0),g.send();var h;if(v.impl.options.imagePlaceholder){var i=v.impl.options.imagePlaceholder.split(/,/);i&&i[1]&&(h=i[1])}})}function k(a,b){return"data:"+b+";base64,"+a}function l(a){return a.replace(/([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g,"\\$1")}function m(a){return function(b){return new Promise(function(c){setTimeout(function(){c(b)},a)})}}function n(a){for(var b=[],c=a.length,d=0;d<c;d++)b.push(a[d]);return b}function o(a){return a.replace(/#/g,"%23").replace(/\n/g,"%0A")}function p(a){var b=r(a,"border-left-width"),c=r(a,"border-right-width");return a.scrollWidth+b+c}function q(a){var b=r(a,"border-top-width"),c=r(a,"border-bottom-width");return a.scrollHeight+b+c}function r(a,b){var c=window.getComputedStyle(a).getPropertyValue(b);return parseFloat(c.replace("px",""))}return{escape:l,parseExtension:b,mimeType:c,dataAsUrl:k,isDataUrl:d,canvasToBlob:f,resolveUrl:g,getAndEncode:j,uid:h(),delay:m,asArray:n,escapeXhtml:o,makeImage:i,width:p,height:q}}function n(){function a(a){return a.search(e)!==-1}function b(a){for(var b,c=[];null!==(b=e.exec(a));)c.push(b[1]);return c.filter(function(a){return!q.isDataUrl(a)})}function c(a,b,c,d){function e(a){return new RegExp("(url\\(['\"]?)("+q.escape(a)+")(['\"]?\\))","g")}return Promise.resolve(b).then(function(a){return c?q.resolveUrl(a,c):a}).then(d||q.getAndEncode).then(function(a){return q.dataAsUrl(a,q.mimeType(b))}).then(function(c){return a.replace(e(b),"$1"+c+"$3")})}function d(d,e,f){function g(){return!a(d)}return g()?Promise.resolve(d):Promise.resolve(d).then(b).then(function(a){var b=Promise.resolve(d);return a.forEach(function(a){b=b.then(function(b){return c(b,a,e,f)})}),b})}var e=/url\(['"]?([^'"]+?)['"]?\)/g;return{inlineAll:d,shouldProcess:a,impl:{readUrls:b,inline:c}}}function o(){function a(){return b(document).then(function(a){return Promise.all(a.map(function(a){return a.resolve()}))}).then(function(a){return a.join("\n")})}function b(){function a(a){return a.filter(function(a){return a.type===CSSRule.FONT_FACE_RULE}).filter(function(a){return r.shouldProcess(a.style.getPropertyValue("src"))})}function b(a){var b=[];return a.forEach(function(a){try{q.asArray(a.cssRules||[]).forEach(b.push.bind(b))}catch(c){console.log("Error while reading CSS rules from "+a.href,c.toString())}}),b}function c(a){return{resolve:function(){var b=(a.parentStyleSheet||{}).href;return r.inlineAll(a.cssText,b)},src:function(){return a.style.getPropertyValue("src")}}}return Promise.resolve(q.asArray(document.styleSheets)).then(b).then(a).then(function(a){return a.map(c)})}return{resolveAll:a,impl:{readAll:b}}}function p(){function a(a){function b(b){return q.isDataUrl(a.src)?Promise.resolve():Promise.resolve(a.src).then(b||q.getAndEncode).then(function(b){return q.dataAsUrl(b,q.mimeType(a.src))}).then(function(b){return new Promise(function(c,d){a.onload=c,a.onerror=d,a.src=b})})}return{inline:b}}function b(c){function d(a){var b=a.style.getPropertyValue("background");return b?r.inlineAll(b).then(function(b){a.style.setProperty("background",b,a.style.getPropertyPriority("background"))}).then(function(){return a}):Promise.resolve(a)}return c instanceof Element?d(c).then(function(){return c instanceof HTMLImageElement?a(c).inline():Promise.all(q.asArray(c.childNodes).map(function(a){return b(a)}))}):Promise.resolve(c)}return{inlineAll:b,impl:{newImage:a}}}var q=m(),r=n(),s=o(),t=p(),u={imagePlaceholder:void 0,cacheBust:!1},v={toSvg:b,toPng:d,toJpeg:e,toBlob:f,toPixelData:c,impl:{fontFaces:s,images:t,util:q,inliner:r,options:{}}};"undefined"!=typeof module?module.exports=v:a.domtoimage=v}(this);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap');

* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; transition: all .3s ease; }
body { color: #333; background-color: #fefefe; font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; }
.wrapper { width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; }
button { color: #fff; background-color: #1a6ce9; padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px; outline: none; border: none; cursor: pointer; font-size: 1.3em; }
button:hover { background-color: #1158c4; }
input#text-input { width: 50%; padding: .5em; outline: none; min-width: 250px; border-radius: 5px; border: 3px solid #333; font-size: calc(80% + 1vw); }
input#text-input:focus { border-color: #1a6ce7a6; }
#html-output { margin: 30px auto; }
.heading { margin: 20px auto; }
#output-location { border-radius: 3px; padding: 10px; }
#img-preview-div { display: none; margin-top: 2vh; border: 1px dashed; }
kbd { display: inline-block; margin: .2em .3em; padding: .1em .6em; font: 400 calc(60% + 1vw)/1.4 'Poppins', sans-serif; background-color: #353535; color: #fff; border: 5px solid #555; border-top: 2px solid #555; border-radius: 3px; }
#output-location:not(kbd) { font-size: calc(70% + 1vw); font-weight: 600; }
h1 { font-size: calc(150% + 1vw); }
p { font-size: calc(40% + 1vw); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="heading">
        <h1>Key2Img</h1>
        <p>A Keyboard Shortcut To Image Generator</p>
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="text-input" placeholder="Example: Ctrl + Alt + C"/>

    <div id="html-output">
        <p>HTML Output</p>
        <p id="output-location">
            <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="btnHolder">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="save-svg">SVG</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="save-png">PNG</button>
    </div>

    <div id="img-preview-div">
        <p>Generated Image</p>
        <div id="img-out-preview"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used [Dom to Image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) JavaScript Library for my simple project, but what i am facing is the generated image's quality is too low, like SVG is infinitely zoomable but PNG's quality is very low, i tried using `{style: {transform: "scale(2)"}}` this option in my `domtoimage.toPng` function but my Image is just overflowed to nothing.

Is there any way to change the height or width of the generated image so that it's quality is high

When i use `transform` style my generated image looks like this

[image: This]

Comment: _"like SVG is infinitely zoomable but PNG's quality is very low"_ - Why do you expect a collection of pixels (png) to behave like a vector graphic (svg)?

Comment: The issue tracker for the library has [some issues related to the quality](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image/issues?q=is%3Aissue+quality) of the resulting image. They all have comments with possible fixes.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks alot i found the solution

Answer (score 3):

Well thanks alot to some people i found out this working solution

```
function saveAsPng() {
    let element = document.getElementById('html-output')
    let scale = 2;

    domtoimage.toPng(element, {
            width: element.clientWidth * scale,
            height: element.clientHeight * scale,
            style: { transform: 'scale('+scale+')', transformOrigin: 'top left'}
        })
        .then(function (dataUrl) { appendImg(dataUrl) })
        .catch(function (error) { console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error); });
}
```